# How do I make image hyperlinks have a background image?

Tags: html, css, image

I want all .jpg links to have a certain background image. so a link on a page like 'http://mysite/myimage.jpg' would automatically be prefixed with a small icon. Actually all links to images, ie .gif .png as well with the same icon. If the link is to a website, ie .htm/.php/.html/.asp it should have a different image. I want it to be through classes in CSS. Any help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, it's using the CSS3 attribute selectors though, so browser implementation varies wildly:

```
a[href$='png'],
a[href$='gif'] {/* styles */}
```

It's basically selecting all links whose `href` attribute ends with (the `$=` part) the file-type extension 'png' or 'gif' (obviously other file-types are similarly possible).

Reference, and further details at: http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/

---

**Edited:**

> So, if I wanted to make a special BG image for just youtube links, would I use `a[href$='youtube'] {/* styles */}`

No, if you wanted it for just YouTube links you could use:

```
a[href*=youtube] { /* css */ }
```

The `*=` is the equivalent of 'contains', though you could use:

```
a[href^=http://www.youtube.com] { /* css */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, both. Yes, in  fact I want all links that link to an image and this code 
a[href$='gif'] {/* styles */}
worked perfectly. I'd seen it before, but the syntax was wrong and didn't work. 

So, if I wanted to make a special BG image for just youtube links, would I use
<code>a[href$='youtube'] {/* styles */}</code>

Comment: Thanks ricebowl, I followed your references and dug around a bit more a[href^=http://example.com] { color: red; } found on http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/ same as your example above. Thanks so much for your help guys, I just needed to know what to look for. You taught me how to fish! that's worth so much

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with CSS selectors + background URL properties.  For example, to include an icon with all IMG tags within an Anchor tag:

```
A IMG { background: url("/icon.png") no-repeat scroll; }
```

Comment: I think he means all links that link *to* an image, rather than all links that *contain* an image (but I have been wrong before, so you might be right).